# Why chemical potential changes as a system approaches chemical equilibrium?

Tags: thermodynamics, equilibrium, chemical-potential

Consider a closed system of constant volume $V$, constant pressure $P$, temperature $T$, and Gibbs energy $G$ that is in thermal and mechanical equilibrium with surroundings. It is filled with $N$ particles of one type.

We divide the system into two components: component 1 which has volume $V_1$, pressure $P$, temperature $T$, particle count $N_1$, chemical potential $\mu_1$, Gibbs energy $G_1$, and component 2 which has volume $V-V_1=V_2$, pressure $P$, temperature $T$, particle count $N-N_1=N_2$, chemical potential $\mu_2$, Gibbs energy $G-G_1=G_2$.

The total change in Gibbs energy for this two-component closed system is

$$dG=dG_1+dG_2=\mu_1 dN_1+\mu_2 dN_2=\mu_1 dN_1-\mu_2 dN_1=(\mu_1-\mu_2)dN_1$$

Suppose the system is initially not in chemical equilibrium $\mu_1>\mu_2$, it will decrease the particle count in component 1 $dN_1<0$ until $dG=0$.

However, I am not sure how $G_1$ and $G_2$ change as the system approaches chemical equilibrium. In terms of Gibbs energy, chemical potential is defined as

$$\mu=\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial N}\right)_{T,P}=\frac{G}{N}$$

Since $G$ and $N$ are extensive quantities, it follows that $\mu$ is an intensive quantity. This means the value of $\mu$ is independent of particle count. For example, even if the particle count is doubled, $\mu$ stays the same.

So I am not sure how it is possible for $\mu_1$ to decrease as $N_1$ decreases if chemical potential is an intensive quantity.

Answer (score 2):

The chemical potential of component $1$ in a mixture with component 2 is
$$\tag{1}
   \mu_1 = \left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial N_1}\right)_{T,P,N_2} \color{red}\neq \frac{G}{N}
$$
Notice that equality you wrote applies only in a one-component system. The relationship between the chemical potentials, the Gibbs energy of the mixture and the number of moles is
$$\tag{2}
   N_1 \mu_1 + N_2 \mu_2 = (N_1+N_2) g = G
$$
A simple example can be given for the case of an ideal mixture. Then
$$\tag{3}
   \mu_i = g_i + RT \ln \frac{N_i}{N_1+N_2}
$$
where $g_i=G_i/N_i$ is the molar Gibbs energy of pure $i$ at the same temperature and pressure as the mixture. This shows that the chemical potential changes with composition.

Comment: Thanks. To be clear, equation 2 says that the total Gibbs energy of the two-component system is the average of chemical potentials of each component (assuming that each component is filled with particles of one type)? I’m not sure how equation 3 is derived. Can you give more details?

Comment: @JimmyYang (i) Yes, your reading of Eq 2 is correct. In fact, the first equation in your post is the differential of my Eq 2. (ii) Eq 3 is a *special* result for *ideal* mixtures, namely mixtures whose enthalpy is $H=n_1 h_1 + n_2 h_2$, and their entropy is $S = N_1 s_1+N_2 s_2 - R(N_1\ln\frac{N_1}{N_1+N_2} + N_2 \ln\frac{N_2}{N_1+N_2})$, where $h_i$ and $s_i$ are the properties of the pure components. Ideal gas mixtures and ideal solutions (solutions of chemically similar molecules) satisfy these equations. Set $G = H-T S$ and you will get to Eq (3).

Comment: I see. If each component is filled with a different particle type, then the total Gibbs energy is $G=N_1\mu_1+N_2\mu_2$? I still have doubts about the $N_1+N_2$ factor. Also, the differential for equation 2 is $\mu_1 dN_1+\mu_2 dN_2=GdN_1+N_1dG+GdN_2+N_2dG$ which reduces to $(\mu_1-\mu_2)dN_1=(N_1+N_2)dG=NdG$. I don't see how it results in my equation $dG=(\mu_1-\mu_2)dN_1$.

Comment: (i) You are right (I corrected it), I should have said $(N_1+N_2)g = G$. (ii) According to the Gibbs-Duhem equation (which is easy to prove), $N_1 d\mu_1+N_2 d\mu_2 = 0$.

Comment: Is equation 3 intensive or extensive? I understand that $g_i$ is intensive but not sure about $RT \ln \frac{N_i}{N_1+N_2}$ term. I don't think that equation is intensive since it changes as $N_i$ changes?

Comment: All terms are intensive: if you double both $N_1$ and $N_2$ the term $\frac{N_1}{N_1+N_2}$ remains unchanged.

Comment: Hmm, if $N_1$ increases, $g_1$ and $N_1+N_2$ stay constant but $\frac{N_1}{N_1+N_2}$ increases which in turn increases $\mu_1$, right?

Comment: If $N_1$ increases with $N_2$ *constant* (see definition of $\mu$), then $\mu$ increases. This is why sometimes we say that the driving force for diffusion is a concentration gradient. In reality, it is a gradient in chemical potential, but in single phase systems $\mu$ and concentration change in the same direction.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of the chemical potential should be $$\mu_1=\left(\frac{\partial G}{\partial N_1}\right)_{T,P,N_2}$$

Comment: You're right, I forgot to write constant $N_2$.